# Hide data source name in lowest zoom mode in Excel

Tags: excel, csv, zooming, datasource

i have a table with a CSV file as a data source. This works fine. But if I zoom out (to the lowest zoom with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>MouseWheel</kbd>) suddenly the name of the data source appears by magic (see below). I can't find a property to disable this name.

[image: Screenshot]

Does anyone have an idea how to disable this name? (I use Excel 2010).

Comment: Please provide more details. Kindly go through this guide : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This is not a programming question per se and may be better-answered at [Super User](https://superuser.com).